# D3 how to draw with complex object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a data set like so:

```
var barData =  [{'label':'Group 1', 'data':[{'x':'Jan 2000','y':0},{'x':'Jan 2001','y':5},{'x':'Jan 2003','y':10},{'x':'Jan 2004','y':0},{'x':'Jan 2005','y':6},{'x':'Jan 2006','y':11},{'x':'Jan 2007','y':9},{'x':'Jan 2008','y':4},{'x':'Jan 2009','y':11},{'x':'Jan 2010','y':2}]},
    {'label':'Group 2', 'data':[{'x':'Jan 2000','y':1},{'x':'Jan 2001','y':6},{'x':'Jan 2003','y':11},{'x':'Jan 2004','y':1},{'x':'Jan 2005','y':7},{'x':'Jan 2006','y':12},{'x':'Jan 2007','y':8},{'x':'Jan 2008','y':3},{'x':'Jan 2009','y':13},{'x':'Jan 2010','y':3}]},  
];
```

So there is an array within an object which is in an array.  I want the result to draw boxes from start date to start date + 30 days.  So for Group 1 there should be a horizontal line of boxes being drawn at each start date.

Here is an image:

[image]

```
var barGroup = chart.append('g');
barGroup.selectAll('g')
.data(barData, function (data) {
    data.data.forEach(function (d, i) {
        var bar = barGroup.append('rect');
        bar.attr('x', x(new Date(d.x)))
           .attr("class", "bar-group")
           .attr('width', 10)
    });
    return data.data
})
.enter()
.append('rect')
//.attr("class", "bar-group")
.attr('height', barY.rangeBand() - 2)
.attr('y', function (data, index) { 
    console.log(data);//i need to loop through this and draw a box for each of these on the same line.
    return barY(index); 
})
.attr('width', width)
.attr('style', 'background: #ccc')
```

Edit:

new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5kLeag9m/3/

I am getting closer, just cant figure out why i cant see the nested rect's

Comment: Have a look at [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

Comment: Please see my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5kLeag9m/3/ how come i cant see the nested rect's?

Comment: You're appending `rect` to `rect` elements, which is invalid. Also, you're not using D3's nested selections, which will make this easier.

Comment: OK I think I am getting closer.  I don't have rect's in rect. and I think I am using D3's nested selections.  Still not seeing my "bar"'s getting drawn.
http://jsfiddle.net/5kLeag9m/4/

Comment: I just needed height.. http://jsfiddle.net/5kLeag9m/6/

Comment: any ideas on how to get the parent index from the children y attribute? 

see comment //0 = parent index

Comment: The parent index is the third argument, i.e. `function(d, i, j)`.